# Presign Buy order without knowing the right amount in advance

Tags: stellar-sdk

How it's possible to create a valid `Manage Buy Offer` in Transaction 5 of the [crowdfunding example](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/walkthroughs/stellar-smart-contracts.html#transaction-5-crowdfunding-fails) from the stellar smart contracts reference.

The reference quotes:

> Manage Buy Offer: Holding account buys participation tokens at a rate of X per token.

But at the time of presigning I don't know how many participation tokens were sold. So which amount should I put into the buy offer?

With the full amount of participation tokens we get `op_underfunded` and without an amount we get `op_malformed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example isn't valid since Stellar protocol version 10, and simply hasn't been removed.

The example was first published in Q1-2018, and migration to v10 happened in Q3.

Since then, there's a requirement for all offers to be fully backed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That answers the question. Do you know any strategy to do a crowdfunding on stellar?